# Retrieving related polymorphic set with django-polymorphic

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have three simple models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    [...]


class AttendanceLog(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, [...])
    from_datetime = models.DateTime([...])
    to_datetime = models.DateTime([...])


class Salary(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, [...])
    [...]
```

What I need is to make a query that will return the total (`SUM`) amount of time an employee was in work (attendance). What I have right now:

```
# method in Salary
def get_attended_hours(self):
    qs = AttendanceLog.objects.employee(self.employee).filter(to_datetime__year=self.year, to_datetime__month=self.month)
    qs = qs.values('employee') # group by employee (should not be needed)
    duration = ExpressionWrapper(F('to_datetime') - F('from_datetime'), output_field=fields.DurationField())
    qs = qs.annotate(duration=Sum(duration)).values_list('duration', flat=True)

    # expected output: {'duration': datetime.timedelta(0, x)}
    # actual output: <AttendanceLogQuerySet [datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 10800), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), datetime.timedelta(0, 14400), '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>

    # qs.query: SELECT SUM(django_timestamp_diff("human_resources_attendancelog"."to_datetime", "human_resources_attendancelog"."from_datetime")) AS "duration" FROM "human_resources_attendancelog" WHERE ("human_resources_attendancelog"."employee_id" = 22 AND "human_resources_attendancelog"."to_datetime" BETWEEN 2017-01-01 00:00:00 AND 2017-12-31 23:59:59.999999 AND django_datetime_extract('month', "human_resources_attendancelog"."to_datetime", None) = 11 AND "human_resources_attendancelog"."attendance_type" = RE) GROUP BY "human_resources_attendancelog"."employee_id", "human_resources_attendancelog"."to_datetime" ORDER BY "human_resources_attendancelog"."to_datetime" ASC

    # problematic part: GROUP BY "human_resources_attendancelog"."employee_id", "human_resources_attendancelog"."to_datetime"
```

Basically, why is it also using `GROUP BY` on `to_datetime`? I tried to force the `GROUP BY` clause by using `qs.values('employee')` but that doesn't remove the `to_datetime`. There should be no `GROUP BY` on this queryset needed because we already filter the data as needed. (I don't want to `GROUP BY` by year or month because business logic reasons.)

Basically the problem is that I need to SUM